# com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment: Cannot resolve symbol "maps"

Tags: android, google-maps

I've followed all of the directions here with no issues:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#getting_the_google_maps_android_api_v2

Finally, I follow the last instruction to test if the map is working, updating my activity_map.xml file with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

However, in the last line, everything after `com.google` is red, and on mouse over I get the message that "Cannot resolve symbol 'MapFragment'.

Any ideas would be a big help right now.

Comment: Have you added Google Play Services lib in your project?

Comment: I'm using Android Studio. I downloaded Google Play Services and the Google Repository through the Android SDK manager and updated my manifest with this code (using the actual key, of course): <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="API_KEY"/>

Comment: Do you have `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.+'` like this line in your `build.gradle` ?

Comment: It has: `dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.11'
}`

Comment: EDIT: Apparently there was some issue with that particular build. When I changed it to the line you had it cleared up the issue. Thanks! If you want to put that as a response, I'll vote it as the answer

Comment: Check : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Do the following to solve the issue:

[image: Install Google Play services]

[image: Go File->Project Structure...]

[image: Dependencies Tab, Add com.google.android.gms]

Finally: click on **"+"** button

[image]

After that, clean and rebuild the project!

Comment: The accepted answer doesn't do any help. This one is the right answer, I've tried it. So I vote this answer as the true answer of the problem.

I wish your answer is also describing in detail how to add play-store dependancy lib by click + button indeed to make it more clear.

Comment: This answer works. Yet, the steps are quite unclear. For me, the most important step was adding `com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0`. This was quite hard do decipher in the last screenshot.

Comment: For me I just needed to add `com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.x.x` rather than the whole `play-services`

Comment: For me, as of Android Version 2.0 try this: in the toolbar click the button 2 options down to the right from the stop button when emulator is running or not running to get to project structure and click your project/app under modules and go to dependencies tab, click the + button select: com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0. Click ok, rebuild. Compile errors should go away.

Comment: There is no such option like "Compile" scope in "Project Structure" window in current Android Studio release. Is this the same as "Compile only"?

Answer (score 24):

**Add google play services to your project**

To make the Google Play services APIs available to your app:

1. Open the build.gradle file inside your application module directory.
2. add a new build rule under dependencies for the latest version of play-services

example

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
...

dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
}
```

3. Save the changes and click Sync Project with Gradle Files  in the toolbar.
4. Open your app's manifest file and add the following tag as a child of the `<application>` element:

   `<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
   android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />`

This steps will remove the above mentioned error.This particular solution is for android studio only.

for more info visit : http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

Comment: Awesome step by step answer +1

Answer (score 10):

```
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:15.0.1"
```

Comment: The `gms:play-services-places` was indeed missing for me.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add this lines in your manifest file:

**Add Following Permission**

```
<permission
        android:name="com.example.mapexdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

**And add this lines in also:**

```
 <meta-data
       android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
       android:value="AIzaSyDxEkfvGvKy.........your api key" />

  <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
      android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Comment: Hope this may help you!

Comment: i am updating an application which is build on eclipse, now i am using android studio and using different package name , does it affect to it, as all apk's have their key on their package name. my error log is `Error:(50, 5) Missing 'name' key attribute on element meta-data at AndroidManifest.xml:50:5
Error:(51, 9) Missing 'name' key attribute on element meta-data at AndroidManifest.xml:51:9
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs`

Comment: after adding `com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY` it work for me. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Add the following libraries to app gradle.

```
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:17.0.0"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the support map fragment

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

Try this it will do the work ....

Comment: hey its not working in my application i used this `<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />` its showing red line under `android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment`. can you help

Comment: yes i have added that problem has resolved but a new arises `Error:(50, 5) Missing 'name' key attribute on element meta-data at AndroidManifest.xml:50:5
Error:(51, 9) Missing 'name' key attribute on element meta-data at AndroidManifest.xml:51:9
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs`

Comment: ty for replying i did the same. so upvoted your comment. :) can you help me with this error.

Comment: it says that there is error in manifest file  can you put you manifest file code

Comment: i am using this piece of code `<meta-data> android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="API_KEY"</meta-data>
        <meta-data> android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"</meta-data>`

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by moving the android `SDK` location to a folder without whitespaces.

Instructions:

1. from android studio open the `SDK Manager`
2. navigate to:

   > System Setings > Android SDK,
3. Check the `Android SDK Location` (third row from the top) whether the folder name contains white spaces (such as `c:\My Documents\Android\SDK`)
4. with the windows file explorer create a new folder and copy the content
5. now with the SDK Manger type edit and change to the new folder

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue . I updated the google play services as well.

Adding the following line, helped me resolving the compilation issue:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.0'
```

to your `app.gradle`.