# Cannot resolve symbol 'maps'

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-api

I imported [mixare](https://github.com/mixare/mixare) source code to Android Studio 3.1 but I get error message `Cannot resolve symbol 'maps'` in following lines:

```
import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;
import com.google.android.maps.Projection;
```

I saw [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26901149/com-google-android-gms-maps-mapfragment-cannot-resolve-symbol-maps) but none of the answers were helpful. How can I fix this?

**build.gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'org.mixare'
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 24
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':mixarelib')
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:12.0.0'
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
  <application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    tools:ignore="AllowBackup"
    tools:replace="android:label">
    <meta-data
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
      android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
      android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
      android:value="(API KEY)" />

    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
...
```

Comment: As I can see in your mixare, it says Google API level 10 and you are using 12. Try changing to version 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this very easily.

Go to **Settings | Appearance & Behavior | Android SDK** and check 'Show Package Details'.

Select SDK version(I selected 7.0), check 'Google APIs' and install it. I don't know why the option doesn't exist in the version 7.1.1 and over.

And configure **build.gradle** like this:

```
compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:24'
```